# Поиск индекса пары символов в строке

Tags: java, строки, char, compare

Есть данные от пользователя напр. ("asfdfg84", 'f', 'g'), где "asfdfg84"- строка, а 'f', 'g'- два символа. Мне нужно вывести индекс первого символа. Если первый символ встречается раз то вывести его индекс, а если первый символ встречается два раза в строке, то вывести индекс второго расположения этого символа, если нет совпадений с первым символом, то тогда проверяем совпадения со вторым символом, а если нет вообще никаких совпадений, то вывести -1. Нужно сделать без использования функции indexOf().

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class TestIndexOf {

    private static String text;
    private  static char ch1, ch2;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TestIndexOf  test = new TestIndexOf();
        test.getInput();
        System.out.println(test.getIndex(text, ch1, ch2));

    }

    public static void getInput() {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter word and chars: ");
        text = scan.nextLine();

        ch1 = scan.next().charAt(0);
        ch2 = scan.next().charAt(0);

    }

    public static int getIndex(String tet, char ch1, char ch2)  {
        int count = 0;
        int  array[] = new int [2];
        int i, j;
        for (i = 0; i < tet.length(); i++) {
          for ( j = 0; j < array.length; j++) {
            if (tet.charAt(i) == ch1) {
               array[j] = i;
            }
          }
          return array[j];
        }

          //
          // if(tet.charAt(i) == ch2) {
          //    count++;
          //    array = new int [count];
          //    for ( j = 0; j < array.length; j++) {
          //       array[j] = i;
          //
          //   }
     return -1;
    }
}
```

Comment: На сколько я понял необходим именно индекс 1-ого или 2-ого вхождения символа. То есть если в строке символ повторяется 3 раза, то нужно именно индекс второго вхождения? Или же просто необходим индекс последнего вхождения?

Comment: Если в строке символ повторяется 3 раза то тогда нужен индекс 3-го раза, но надо учесть что если будет только раз то тогда надо этот индекс.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Простейший пирмер на C#

```
int getLastIndex(String str, char a, char b)
{
    int ind = getLastIndex(str, a);
    if (ind > -1) return ind;
    return getLastIndex(str, b);
}

int getLastIndex(String str, char c){
    for(int i=str.Length-1; i>=0; i--)
        if(str[i] == c) return i;
    return -1;
}
```

Comment: Спасибо за пример!

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте так:

```
public static int getIndex(String str, char ch1, char ch2)  {
    int index =
            getIndex(str, ch1, 2);
    return index > -1 ?
            index :
            getIndex(str, ch2, 1);
}

// В случае, если необходимо n-ое вхождение символа
public static int getIndex(String str, char ch, int maxOrdinal) {
    int index = -1;
    int found = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
        if (str.charAt(i) == ch) {
            index = i;
            if (++found >= maxOrdinal) {
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return index;
}

// В случае, если необходимо последнее вхождение символа
public static int getLastIndex(String str, char ch) {
    for (int i = str.length() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        if (str.charAt(i) == ch) {
            return i;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Вывод:

```
Enter word and chars: 
asfdfg84
f
g
4
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! А что значит   --- return index > -1 ?  --- в первом методе?

Comment: @DimaMargita [Тернарная условная операция](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%83%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F)